# I have PhpMyAdmin error with config file

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

When i open my localhost/phpmyadmin in my lampp server ubuntu then this phpmyadmin file shows this error,

```
"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."
```

Comment: Did you click to find out why?

Comment: That's a shame. Good luck fixing it. Did you have a question?

Comment: yes i clicked there then its shows  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] ...  OK
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
General relation features: Disabled
 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Display Features: Disabled
 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Creation of PDFs: Disabled
 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Displaying Column Comments: Disabled
Browser transformation: Disabled
---these type of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here."
Hi my be it's use fulll

"https://askubuntu.com/questions/261858/the-phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured"

Comment: Its fair help @sumit. Voteup my question if you think this will be useful for others you earned badget to vote up. So use it.